# Framework crash when printing an XPS document

Tags: .net, printing, xps

I have a .NET 4.0 application that sends FixedDocument objects to a printer using an XpsDocumentWriter.  I have encountered an application crash in a few scenarios.  As far as I can tell it is a compatibility issue with XPS and certain print drivers.  I am including a stack trace below.  I would like to either make it work properly or identify the problem before the crash so I can prevent users from attempting to print to a printer that will cause an application crash.  I am unable to catch the exception in a try catch block since the exception is thrown on another thread in some external code.

My code looks similar to this:

```
Dim printQueue as PrintQueue
'initialize printQueue
Dim printDocument as FixedDocument
'initialize printDocument
'add content to printDocument
Dim writer As XpsDocumentWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(printQueue)
AddHandler writer.WritingCompleted, AddressOf WriteDocumentComplete
writer.WriteAsync(printDocument, printQueue.UserPrintTicket)
```

I have tried looking in the registry to determine if a print driver is based on Microsofts Universal Print Driver, but that doesn't seem like a reliable method.  I have some printers that don't appear to have an explicit dependency that work fine.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Print\Environments\Windows NT x86\Drivers\Version-3\Microsoft XPS Document Writer

Stack Trace from the Application Event Log:

> Application: MyApp.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Stack:
>      at Microsoft.Internal.AlphaFlattener.MetroDevice0.AssertState(DeviceState, DeviceState)
>      at Microsoft.Internal.AlphaFlattener.MetroToGdiConverter.EndDocument()
>      at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.NgcSerializationManagerAsync.EndDocument(Boolean)
>      at System.Windows.Xps.Serialization.NgcSerializationManagerAsync.InvokeSaveAsXamlWorkItem(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
>      at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
>      at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
>      at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
>      at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
>      at System.Windows.Application.Run()
>      at MyApp.Application.Main()
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

**Update:**
I spoke with Microsoft.  I was told that there is no work around and it will be fixed in .NET 4.5.

Comment: What does your printing code look like?

Comment: Strange exception.  The assertion that failed was that printing was started before it ends printing.  This is Microsoft Support material.

Comment: Jon, my print code is fairly simple.  I edited my question to include an example.